# Change board color to red on input validation with jquery?

Tags: validation

Does anyone have any examples of input validation changing the input border color to red?

Thanks.

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to keep as much of the styling as you can in the *style*-sheets.  Defined a

```
input.invalid {
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

and use `.addClass("invalid")` on your elements